# How to select columns with specified values and sort them with number of occurrences of specified values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE product like '%abc%' OR product like '%cde%'
```

Is it possible to display all products with

```
both 'abc' and 'cde' first
```

and then products with

```
either 'abc' or 'cde'
```

Comment: Case expression in the ORDER BY.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE (product like '%abc%' OR product like '%cde%') order by column1,column2 asc

Comment: @RafaelShkembi, you missed the order part.

Comment: @jarlh i'am sorry but i don't get it.. could you please tell me where i'am wrong?

Comment: i know the simple order function. But i need to display columns with abc and cde first.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi, check my answer below.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi ok let me try

Comment: @jarlh i got it when you post it. That's why i upvote it. Simple without sub querys

Comment: @RafaelShkembi column1, column2 ? what you mean?

Comment: @jdoe you can use jarlh solution bellow. It's what you are looking for

Comment: so when are you going to post your question about an unresponsive website and queries taking forever to execute?

Comment: @e4c5 sorry i diidn't get you.

Comment: like %something% is a database killer. You have two of them in your query. Then you are ordering on a derived field. Start drafting that question.

Comment: @e4c5 what else i should use to select colums?

Comment: hard to say http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY` a `case` expression that returns 1 if both abd and cde, or else 2.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE product like '%abc%' OR product like '%cde%'
ORDER BY case when product like '%abc%' AND product like '%cde%' then 1
              else 2
         end
```

Comment: can you please post it like php mysql way. So that i can test it

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I thought that there could be different records for each product , 1 that answers the first condition and one that answer the second .

Comment: @jdoe, I don't know php, or MySQL (very well). This is ANSI SQL, and is expected to run on all dbms products, including MySQL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a correlated query in the `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table t
WHERE product like '%abc%' OR product like '%cde%'
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product) FROM table s
          WHERE t.<Relation> = s.<Relation>
           AND s.product like '%abc%' OR s.product like '%cde%') DESC
```

Replace `<Relation>` with the tables key .

Answer (score 0):

For refined ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE product like '%abc%' OR product like '%cde%'
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        /* First show products with 'abc' AND 'cde'... */
        WHEN product LIKE '%abc%' AND product LIKE '%cde%' THEN 1
        /* ...2nd products with with 'abc' */
        WHEN product LIKE '%abc%' THEN 2 
        /* ...and finally products with with 'cde' */
        WHEN product LIKE '%cde%' THEN 3 
        ELSE 4 /* not actually necessary in this case */
    END
```